# How to execute a fuction based on the value of a string?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a string, and I want to execute a function with the same name as the srings value. Of course I could use a billion

```
if() {

} else {

if() {

} else {

}}
```

statements, but given I have like 20 functions, that isn't really an elegant solution.

So if I have something like:

```
exampleString = "helloWorld"

function helloWorld() {

    console.log("Hello World")
}
```

So how do I now execute the function? I expect there's propably a way to do something like this

```
`${exampleString}`.execute()
```

or something similar.

So how can I take the value of the string, and use it in the code?

Comment: You could use eval, but I would strongly advice against.  A better option is to use a map, and basically map the string to the functions.

Answer (score 3):

You can stick the function in a map / object.

```js
const funcMap = { cowSay: console.log }

funcMap['cowSay']('web')
```